# How to open login url in browser inside app and pass value to react-native?

Tags: react-native, expo, react-navigation, react-navigation-v6

I am learning react-native, so pretty new to it. I am curious how to implement browser sign-in and then pass value to store in AsyncStorage.

> As an example AWS Console app redirects to signin.aws.amazon.com to sign in and after sign in it log me inside their app

Is there any github repository or youtube video to learn that. I am using expo & react-navigation v6 to navigate between screen.

Thank You!

Comment: It is important to know what it is you are trying to "sign-in to".  And how that is integrated into your overall system.  You might consider reading the [Expo docs page on Authentication](https://docs.expo.dev/develop/authentication/).

Comment: I already had an existing backend and and a product ui to login, If I don't want to login creating Login Screen in react-native, rather go to Web url and login and get the token response from web then pass it to react native.

Comment: What is your backend authentication technology?

Comment: Have you looked at [using a webview](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/webview/) for your existing Login Screen?

Comment: I am using node + express + mongo for backend

Comment: Okay but what are you using for authentication?  Is it Passport?